# IPTables: DNAT working for every port I define except 443 (HTTPS)

Tags: iptables, routing, firewall, nat

My IPTables already had content inside it that I'm not sure what generated it.

I'm tying to point traffic with specific ports to an internal bridge adapter for a virtual machine.

Every port I have defined has worked except 443. What is stopping 443 from working?

My IPTables Config:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [790:89144]
:INPUT ACCEPT [696:84869]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [94:4275]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [532:331824]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [626:336099]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 28 16:44:01 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Sep 28 16:44:01 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [696:84869]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [532:331824]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.122/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.122/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.122/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4357 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.122/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 28 16:44:01 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Sep 28 16:44:01 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [9:468]
:INPUT ACCEPT [9:468]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [40:2528]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [60:3568]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.20.112/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.122:1883
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.20.112/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4357 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.122:4357
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.20.112/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.122:443
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.20.112/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.122:8123
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 28 16:44:01 2022
```

Comment: iptables filter rules here  are silly and effectivly do nothing because policy is "accept". Output ports should be sport not dport but in this garbage it goesnt metter. They are like a garbage. Only dnat rules make sense in this garbage. Just one MASQUERADE is enough.  As  for dnat 443 tcp its ok should work **so problem not in iptables**

Comment: Side questions: are you also running Docker in the same place? Where are the tests made from? Is port 443 not connecting, or is it connecting fine and then an actual HTTPS request fails?